# HTTPS post login form

Tags: python, https

Trying to find a way to send a POST HTTPS request from Python to a web page form

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html) is for the job, and you may refer to the example code at the bottom of the document. and google for the httplib sample code.

Comment: Uh, he actually gave you a good pointer to how to solve this. It is somewhat outside of SO etiquette to then ask that he write your code for you.